# Calculate Electric Field on the Z-axis from a finite charge wire

Tags: calculus, physics, mathematical-physics, electromagnetism

I've been trying to find the electric Field on the Z-axis from a non-uniform charge density line charge. The wire is placed on the z-axis from $z=0$ to $z=1$, $E=?$ at $z>1$ and $z<0$

$$
\rho =2z
$$

Here is my thought process:

$$
P_{1} = (0,0,z), P_{2} = (0,0,-z)
$$
$$
\vec{a_1}=(z-1)\hat{z},\vec{a_2}=-z\hat{z}
$$
$$
\hat{a_{1,2}}=\hat{z}
$$
$$
E_r=\frac1{4πϵ_0} \int_{}^{} \hat{a_{1,2}} *\frac\rho{R^2}  \,dl
$$
$$
E_{z>1}=\frac1{4πϵ_0} \int_{0}^{1} \hat{z} *\frac{2z}{(z-1)^2}  \,dz
$$
$$
E_{z>1}=\frac1{4πϵ_0} [ln{|z-1|}-\frac1{z-1}]  \,\begin{matrix}
1\\
0
\end{matrix}
$$
Now I reach where I have an issue. I get an undefined Electric Field, I think I messed up on the setup, but i don't know where. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You are using the same variable to denote different things. You should compute
$$
E_{z>1}=\frac{\hat{z}}{4πϵ_0} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{2\ell}{(z-\ell)^2}  \,d\ell.
$$